# How to show/hide multiple object using props from child to parent to child

Tags: reactjs

My idea of design is quit simple. I have sidebar in child components (Aside.js), and Main object display content (Main.js), all of them are use in ImportPage.
In Aside I have three buttons and I want to show and hide content in Main.

Aside.js

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("Motywacja");
function changeMoto(){
  setValue("Motywacja");
}
function changeInspi() {
  setValue("Inspiracja");
}
function changeFinanse() { 
  setValue("Finanse");
 }

  return (
    <ProSidebar>
      <SidebarHeader style={headerStyle}>Podkategorie</SidebarHeader>
      <SidebarContent>
        <Menu iconShape="circle">
          <MenuItem onClick={changeMoto}>Motywacja</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={changeInspi}>Inspiracja</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onCLick={changeFinanse}>Finansowanie</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
 
      </SidebarContent>
    </ProSidebar>
```

ImportPage.js

```
if(value == "motywacja"){
    <Main data="col1"/>   }
    if(value = "finanse"){ 
    return <main data="col2"/>
    }
    if value == "inspiracja") { return <main data="col3" />}
```

Main.js

```
if(data = col 3) return titlecol3 and contentcol3
if data = col 2 return ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept I believe you're looking for is called [Lifting State](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Essentially, you pass the handler down as a prop from `Import` to `Aside`. This can be the set function of `useState`,

ie. `[myState, setMyState] = useState();` can be passed as `<Aside setMyState={setMyState} />`

Now that the state is in `Import` you can easily pass it down to `Main.js` via props and display whatever you wish based on the value you set.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your issue is very common and easy when using concept of props and state.
First, you need to move *value* state to *ImportPage* component so that you can use on that component.
About change value of *value* state when click button on Aside component, let pass *setValue* as props to Aside

```
<Aside onValueChange={setValue} />
```

Aside.js

```
export default function Aside(props) {
   function changeMoto(){
      props.onValueChange("Motywacja");
   }
   ....
}
```

On ImportPage component, you just need to render only one Main component and dynamic props:

```
<Main data={value === 'Motywacja' ? 'col1' : value === 'Finacel' ? 'col2' : 'col3' } />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the states in the parent component, in one component you set the value and in the other you use the value

ImportPage.js

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("Motywacja");

<Aside setValue={setValue}/>
<Main value={value}/>
```

of course you can set and use wherever you need just know that if brother components need the same state you need to initiate it in the parent

Aside.js

```
export const Aside = ({setValue}) => {
    function changeInspi() {
       setValue("Inspiracja");
    }
```

Main.js

```
export const Main = ({value}) => {
    if(value == "motywacja"){
      .........
    } else {
      ........
    }
```

Comment: I tried ``` export const Aside = ({setValue}) => {}  ```  but 
I have ```Syntax error: Identifier 'setValue' has already been declared. ``` after trying to pass method as props lifter.

Comment: if you passed it as props, remove the declared state `const [value, setValue] = useState();` in that component or rename it `const [water, setWater]....`